# subsets with predefined sequences

Tags: combinatorics, modular-arithmetic

I have a set $N=\{m,m+1,m+2,...,n\}$
And there are some generating functions of the format :

$f(x,k) = (x^2 -1) \mod k$,

where $k \le \sqrt m$ and $k$ is in the form $(6i+1)$ or $(6i-1)$, $\forall i$.

for example:Let k=5. Then f(x,5) will have one of the values from the set {4,0,3,3,0}

How can we get the maximum number of elements in $N$ which are not part of any $f(x,k)$?

We can generate $f(x,k)$ for all $k$ and check sequentially. Is there a better alternative where without performing the search we can directly get the answer?

Comment: don't use programming syntax

Comment: sure. Re-did the paragraph, Thanks

Comment: Is $m$ integer here? How did you get the set $\{1, 0, 1, 1, 0\}$ for $f(x, 5)$? Can you explain it in more detail?

Comment: m is indeed integer. consider k=5, x= 88. f(88,5) = (88^2-1) mod 5.

Comment: sorry for the incomplete edit last time. I updated the paragraphs above. Hope it's clearer now